# Increment each of X value of transform attr by 50

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transform, translate

I am trying to increment the `transform translate X value` of each of the images by 50. I am able to do that with the width. Is there anyways I can do that with the the `transform translate X value`

Expected Result:

```
transform="translate(64.5,0)
transform="translate(114.5,0)
transform="translate(164.5,0)
```

This is my code to increment each of the width:

HTML:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('.what-can-we-do-tash').css('width', function(i){
   return $(this).width() + (i * 50);
});
```

Can I do something similar for `transform translate` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
$('.what-can-we-do-tash').css('transform', function(i, s) {
   return s.replace(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?(, ?\d+\))/, (s, t, u, v) => `${parseFloat(t + u) + 50 * (i + 1)}${v}`)
});
```

```css
.what-can-we-do-tash {
  transform: translate(100.5px ,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="what-can-we-do-tash">
```

Comment: Thanks, but this adds the same translate value to all... I want each of them to increment by 50. Like 50, 100, 150

Comment: I had a quick question. Why does my code break when in the CSS i set my initial transform value to a decimal value like 58.5?

Comment: It shouldn't break - I tried changing my css to a decimal and it didn't break. The decimal will be lost with my code. Does your code break or are you just losing the decimal?

Comment: It doesnt break but the 50 is added to the decimal, so it shows up as 58.55, 58.105, 58.155. It doesnt do anything when I take out the `px` though from the CSS

Comment: you're welcome :) Just made another edit `parseInt` -> `parseFloat`

Comment: One last question, is there anyway I can I can leave the first img tag as the one set, i.e. 100.5 and increment to that from there? sp 100.5, 150.5, 200.5, 250.5?

Comment: sure, just change `(i + 1)` to `i`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! This really helped with me aligining my ticks on the d3 chart!